# Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key, whats the fastes way now?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have a really short question. I am about to upload my app in the Play Store. While uploading my AppBundle had some mistakes, so I did everything again with a new key. After this, the Play Console came up with the error in the title.

Now my question: As my app isn't released, is it the best way to just delete the app from my dashboard and make a new one, with my new key? Or do I need the same key for the new app??

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event that the first version of the application has been uploaded, you must use the first **key**.

> **Note :** You must save it for future update.

But if you want to completely delete the application from the Google Play Console, you must create a new **key** and the process will be successful.

The best solution for you, if there is the first **key**, there is no need to repeat the steps again.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer. I didn't find the key, so I deleted the app and created a new key.

Comment: Do you have an idea how long the app-checking lasts in the play store?

Comment: In the past, the period was between one to two days, but due to the current circumstances it takes from three days to a week at most.
But it can be accepted quickly if it does not break policy @rottler35